# Injecting request ID in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want to maintain an ID (`Guid.NewGuid()` will suffice) throughout processing request so later I can check logs for a given ID. I'm also returning the ID to the caller in response headers (and messages) in case of an error, they have a reference.

First I did this in the application's Global.asax `Application_BeginRequest()` method, where I put the ID in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context != null)
    {
        var reqguid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
        context.Items.Add("sessionid", reqguid);
    }
}
```

This worked fine in previous applications, but I felt a bit iffy about using `HttpContext` in a "modern" Web API application.

Then I turned to Action Filters, because apparently that's the bees knees for Web API

```
public class ManageRequestHeadersFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("sessionid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var sessionId = actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties["sessionid"].ToString();
        if (sessionId != null)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("App-Session-Id", sessionId);
        }
    }
}
...
config.Filters.Add(new ManageRequestHeadersFilter());
```

This worked OK too, until I wanted to get to the `Request` object in the `ApiController` constructor to set a helper property to the ID. Since the controller constructor runs before the filter, the `Request` object is null. Again, I could probably use the `HttpContext.Current` way, but that beats the purpose of filters.

I also thought of using dependency injection (already using Autofac) to inject the ID into the constructor, which again, worked, but now I'd be doing things a bit backwards which feels weird to my original train of thought.

My feeling is that passing in the ID as a controller constructor parameter will ultimately be the winner, because when Unit Testing, I shouldn't be relying on anything HTTP anyway.

Is there already a best practice for this?

Comment: What's the proble with using `HttpContext`? It's one of the most basic classes in ASP.NET. Even for unit testing, it can be mocked away.